# Как сделать такое уведомление внизу (где написано "нет подключения") как в приложении Youtube?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать такое уведомление внизу (где написано "нет подключения") как в приложении Youtube?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте Snackbar либо делайте свою разметку такого уведомления и отображает её в нужный момент http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/android-support-design.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar).
Насколько мне известно Snackbar не позволяет использовать кастомные layout. Но можно попробовать использовать такой лайфхак:

```
// Создаем Snackbar
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(containerLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
// Получаем лейаут снэкбара
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
// Прячем текст
TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Инфлейтим наш кастомвью
View snackView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_snackbar, null);
// Настраиваем вью
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
TextView textViewTop = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.text);
textViewTop.setText(text);
textViewTop.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

//Если вью не охватывает весь лейаут - добавьте эту строку
layout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

// Добавить вью на лейаут
layout.addView(snackView, 0);
// Показать снекбар
snackbar.show();
```